# In 18.04 ubuntu, after Xrdp login the windows just closes aka xrdp is not working

Tags: 18.04, xrdp

I have updated the Ubuntu system

```
sudo apt-get update
```

In addition I have installed xrdp

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Also, i have installed the default gui and xFCE4.
Moreover, I have echo the xsession.

When I use the vSphere as local user the Gui works fine and loads to xfCE4 or the default with no problems.

[image: xrdp.Service]

Comment: I have also turned off firewall to make sure it was not related to my issue.